How to convert a wide table with repeated column heads to a long table by stacking repeat columns using Python/Pandas
I have a wide table with a group of repeating columns. I would like to transform it by stacking up the repeated columns based on an index also in the table.
The original table is like:
Original table
The desired outcome is like:
Desired outcome
Can I achieve the result with Pandas in Python?
I tried with repeat_columns, group_by etc. but all with errors… am newbie here, how can find some helps!
